# Web Scraping : returning a single script instead of full source code (python request)

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib

Basically I'm trying to get source code from a web-site to display some info in a GUI for personal use. It was fine until today. Request is now returning:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
try{if (!window.CloudFlare) {var CloudFlare=[{verbose:0,p:1488589563,byc:0,owlid:"cf",bag2:1,mirage2:0,oracle:0,paths:{cloudflare:"/cdn-cgi/nexp/dok3v=1613a3a185/"},atok:"bf044f0277d5959921a2a72c3d75c8e3",petok:"a032d4a7f881ace71dd54654ee2fd5265b3404f3-1488641637-1800",zone:"<site link here>",rocket:"a",apps:{}}];document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/nexp/dok3v=f2befc48d1/cloudflare.min.js"><'+'\/script>');}}catch(e){};
//]]>
</script>
```

I've read what CloudFlare is and their rocket scripts, tried other user-agents and used a library that deals with CloudFlare anti-ddos system (which I don't think this web-site uses, there is no "Checking your browser(...)" nor a captcha either). I can't manage to get around this.
This is part of my code:

```
user_agent = "<an user agent here>"
header = {'User-Agent':user_agent}
r = urllib.request.Request("<website url here>",None,header)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(r)
data = response.read()
```

then I parsed the info and etc...
Is there a way to bypass this? I tried using this [library](https://github.com/Anorov/cloudflare-scrape) but couldn't manage to get it working.
This is the [link](http://arenavision.in/schedule) I'm trying to parse some info from

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io). I tried it on a website protected by cloudflare ddos and it worked:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')
driver.get('website-protected-by-cloudflare-ddos')
try:
    # wait until certain element with id 'expected-id' showed up
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'expected-id'))
    )
    # do whatever you want with the page
    print(driver.title)
finally:
    driver.quit()
```